# How to compress (aggregate) data as fast as possible?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I save stock data in a mySql table @ frame 1 minute, so that 1 row is 1 minute data. Data saved are as follow

[image]

Since market session ranges from 0900 up to 1730, I have 511 rows for each day.

I need to compress (aggregate) these intra-day data into 1 daily data (one row only), so that

**daily open** -> first intra-day open value (0900 open value)

**daily high** -> highest value for all 511 intra-day value rows

**daily low** -> lowest value for all 511 intra-day value rows

**daily close** -> latest intra-day traded value (1730 close value)

**daily volume** -> sum of all 511 intra-day volume value rows

I need to perform this compression as fast as possibile since I would plot hundreds of daily data.

Any help really appreciated: here is my full code

```
    import importexportdata.DataItem;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import java.text.ParseException;
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Calendar;
   import java.util.LinkedList;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;

   public class AggregateByDay {    

    String  dbTabName  = "";    
    String  sTimeFrom = "";
    String  sTimeTo = "";    
    short   iTotBar = 0;
    boolean volumeFieldIsOnTable;
    LinkedList<DataItem> data_aggregated = null;
    Dividends dividendsHdl = null;

    Connection  con = null;                
    ResultSet   rs  = null; 
    Statement   st  = null;
    PreparedStatement selectReview=null;    
    Statement         stmtPrepareInitRow=null;
    ResultSet         rsSelectPrepareInitRow  = null;

    public AggregateByDay(String dbTabName, String timeFrom, String timeTo, short iTotBar, boolean volumeFieldIsOnTable, Dividends dividendsHdl){        
        this.dbTabName              = dbTabName;
        this.sTimeFrom              = timeFrom;
        this.sTimeTo                = timeTo;        
        this.iTotBar                = iTotBar;                
        this.volumeFieldIsOnTable   = volumeFieldIsOnTable;
        this.dividendsHdl           = dividendsHdl;
    }

    private void connectToDb(){
        try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                //String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/borsaitalia?" +
                //                        "user="+_dBUserName+"&password="+_dBPassword;

                String connectionUrl = DbConnect.getConnectionUrl();

                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } //end try Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");               
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error  "+ ex.getMessage ()+" "+ex.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }        
    }

    private String getLastFirstDayLower(String _date, String _DbTabName){
        String lastDate = "";

        try {     
                st = con.createStatement();
                if ( "".equals(_date)) {
                    //Get the most recent date
                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM "+_DbTabName+" ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 1;");
                }
                else{
                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM "+_DbTabName+" WHERE date < "+_date+" ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 1;");
                }
                while (rs.next()){
                    lastDate  = rs.getString("date");                                        
                }

                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                    st = null;
                }
        } //end try Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");               
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error  "+ ex.getMessage ()+" "+ex.toString());
        } 
        return lastDate;        
    }

    private String getLastFirstDayLowerNext(String _date, String _DbTabName){
        String lastDate = "";

        try {                     
                if (rsSelectPrepareInitRow.next()){
                    lastDate  = rsSelectPrepareInitRow.getString("date");                                        
                }
                //System.out.println("lastDate "+lastDate);
        } //end try Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");               
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error  "+ ex.getMessage ()+" "+ex.toString());
        } 
        return lastDate;        
    }

    private LinkedList<DataItem> getDbOneMinuteDataForDay(String _date, String _sTimeFrom, String _sTimeTo){

        String sDate = "", sTime = "";
        double dOpen = 0d,  dHigh = 0d, dLow = 0d, dClose = 0d;
        int    iVolume = 0;
        float  dividendsValue = 0;

        LinkedList<DataItem> init_one_minute_data = new LinkedList<>();
        try { 
                selectReview.setString(1, _date);
                selectReview.setString(2, _sTimeFrom);
                selectReview.setString(3, _sTimeTo);
                rs = selectReview.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()){

                    sDate  = rs.getString("date");
                    sTime  = rs.getString("time");
                    dOpen   = rs.getDouble("open");
                    dHigh   = rs.getDouble("high");
                    dLow    = rs.getDouble("low");
                    dClose  = rs.getDouble("close");

                    if (volumeFieldIsOnTable)
                        iVolume = rs.getInt("volume"); 
                    else
                        iVolume = 0;

                    DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();

                    java.util.Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm").parse(sDate+" "+sTime);
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    dataItem.setDate(date);

                    if (dividendsHdl != null) {
                        dividendsValue = dividendsHdl.getTotalDividendsFromDate(sDate);
                    }
                    dataItem.setOpen(dOpen-dividendsValue);
                    dataItem.setHigh(dHigh-dividendsValue);
                    dataItem.setLow(dLow-dividendsValue);
                    dataItem.setClose(dClose-dividendsValue);
                    dataItem.setVolume(iVolume);

                    init_one_minute_data.add(dataItem);                                               
                }
        } //end try Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");               
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error  "+ ex.getMessage ()+" "+ex.toString());
        }/* catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }*/

        return init_one_minute_data;
    }

    public void getAggregateValue(ArrayList<DataItem> externalDataList) {

        String                  sDate;
        short                   count_min;
        Calendar                calendarCurrWeek = null;
        int                     i, n;
        boolean                 end;
        LinkedList<DataItem>    one_minute_data = null;
        LinkedList<DataItem>    data_one_day_aggregated = new LinkedList<>();
        java.util.Date          dDateTimeRgp = null;
        int                     iVolumeRaggruppato = 0;
        double                  dOpenRgp = 0d,  dHighRgp = 0d, dLowRgp = 0d, dCloseRgp = 0d;

        data_aggregated = new LinkedList<>();

        connectToDb();
        sDate = getLastFirstDayLower("", dbTabName);
        if ( "".equals(sDate) ) {
            return;
        }

        end = false;

        try {
            //selectPrepareInitRow = con.prepareStatement("SELECT date FROM "+DbTabName+" WHERE date < ? ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 1;");            

            stmtPrepareInitRow = con.createStatement();
            rsSelectPrepareInitRow = stmtPrepareInitRow.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM "+dbTabName+" WHERE date < "+sDate+" ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC;");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        if (volumeFieldIsOnTable) {
            try {

                selectReview = con.prepareStatement("SELECT open, high, low, close, volume, date, time FROM "+dbTabName+" WHERE date = ? AND time >= ? AND time <= ? ORDER BY time ASC;");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }   
        else {
            try {
                selectReview = con.prepareStatement("SELECT open, high, low, close, date, time FROM "+dbTabName+" WHERE date = ? AND time >= ? AND time <= ? ORDER BY time ASC;");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        do {
            count_min = 1;
            iVolumeRaggruppato   = -1;
            i = 0;
            DataItem one_minute_data_item;

            one_minute_data = getDbOneMinuteDataForDay(sDate, sTimeFrom, sTimeTo);
            n = one_minute_data.size();

            while ((i < n)&&(!end)){
                one_minute_data_item = one_minute_data.get(i);

                if (count_min == 1){
                    iVolumeRaggruppato = one_minute_data_item.getVolume();
                    dOpenRgp    = one_minute_data_item.getOpen();
                    dHighRgp    = one_minute_data_item.getHigh();
                    dLowRgp     = one_minute_data_item.getLow();                                        

                    dDateTimeRgp = one_minute_data_item.getDate();                
                }
                else{
                    iVolumeRaggruppato += one_minute_data_item.getVolume();

                    if (dHighRgp < one_minute_data_item.getHigh()) {
                        dHighRgp = one_minute_data_item.getHigh();
                    }

                    if (dLowRgp > one_minute_data_item.getLow()) {
                        dLowRgp  = one_minute_data_item.getLow();
                    }                   
                }
                dCloseRgp   = one_minute_data_item.getClose();

                if (i == (n-1)){                    
                    DataItem dataItemRgp = new DataItem();
                    dataItemRgp.setDate(dDateTimeRgp);
                    dataItemRgp.setOpen(dOpenRgp);
                    dataItemRgp.setHigh(dHighRgp);
                    dataItemRgp.setLow(dLowRgp);
                    dataItemRgp.setClose(dCloseRgp);
                    dataItemRgp.setVolume(iVolumeRaggruppato);

                    data_one_day_aggregated.add(dataItemRgp);                     
                    count_min = 1;                    
                }
                else {
                    count_min++;
                }
                 i++;
            }//end while ((i < n)&&(!end))

            one_minute_data.clear();

            //fine raggruppamento di 1 intero giorno, inserisco i dati            
            if  (data_one_day_aggregated.size() > 0){
                if (data_aggregated.size() >= iTotBar) {
                    end = true;
                }
                else {
                    data_aggregated.addFirst(data_one_day_aggregated.get(0));
                }             
            }
            data_one_day_aggregated.clear();

            if (!end){                
                sDate = getLastFirstDayLowerNext(sDate, dbTabName);
                if (sDate.equals("")) {
                    end = true;
                }
            }

        } while (!end);

        if (stmtPrepareInitRow != null) {
            try {
                stmtPrepareInitRow.close();
                stmtPrepareInitRow = null;                                
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        if (selectReview != null) {
            try {
                selectReview.close();
                selectReview = null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AggregateByDay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        one_minute_data.clear();
        data_one_day_aggregated.clear();

        if ((data_aggregated != null)&&(data_aggregated.size() > 0)) {
            externalDataList.ensureCapacity(data_aggregated.size()); 

            for (DataItem item : data_aggregated) {
                externalDataList.add(item);            
            } 
        }

        data_aggregated.clear();
    }    
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with existing code in other word what is your question exactly WRT code

Comment: Can't you just do a "select sum(...) ..." in your query?  Also, why do you have date and time as separate fields?

Comment: this is my problem: my code is working, but it takes 40 seconds to get 300 daily rows: I need to speed up this process

Comment: I prefer to keep date and time in separate fields for intra-day time frame plots